# How to change GnoCanvas.canvas's aa(anti-aliasing) flag

Tags: canvas, ocaml, gnome

I made a `GnoCanvas.canvas` object in LablGTK2.

```
let new_canvas = GnoCanvas.canvas ~aa:true ~width:width ~height:height ()
```

I sometimes want to change the antia-aliasing flag `aa` from `false` to `true`. Can I change this flag after initialisation of the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change `aa` after defining the canvas because this operation is not supported by the underlying [libgnomecanvas library](https://developer.gnome.org/libgnomecanvas/stable/GnomeCanvas.html).

Comment: @mmsss You are welcome.  Do not forget that you can *accept* the answer if you think it answers adequately your question.